# Images to rename

Tags: powershell

Thousands of images that follow this pattern:
1 is the main image and this is the problem image because I don't have anything to select.

```
1) 6-100-DS.tif - Renamed to 6-100-DS-main.tif
2) 6-100-DS_a.tif - Renamed to 6-100-DS-alt01.tif
3) 6-100-DS_b.tif - Renamed to 6-100-DS-alt02.tif
```

Renaming 2 & 3 is easy enough:

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_a","-alt01" }
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_b","-alt02" }
```

I may have answered my own question; I suppose I could just rename all images "-main.tif" and then include that in the selector for renaming the alt images.

```
"_a-main.tif", "_b-main.tif"
```

Anyone know how to do this more efficiently?

Comment: I tried Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace ".","-main." } but that was in error so what I really need to do is find the end of the file name and add "-main" to the end before the ".tif"

Comment: The "DS" isn't actually part of every image name. I want to add a suffix on to every image.

Comment: 1) 6-100-DS.tif - Renamed to 6-100-DS-main.tif
2) 6-100-DS_a.tif - Renamed to 6-100-DS_a-main.tif
3) 6-100-DS_b.tif - Renamed to 6-100-DS_b-main.tif

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear about thsi

The pattern being: the original base image needs to have a suffix of "-main" while the _a, _b, _c...need to be "-alt01, -alt02, alt03..." 

My own solution was to just add a suffix on the end of every image name. So, every image would end in -main. I would then go back and do a replace of the _a-main, _b-main...with -alt01, -alt02.

I'll give it a try. Thank.

Comment: So that solution worked really well by adding -main to all the base images. 

Now I just need to go through and do each of the _a, _b... images.

Comment: What happened, where did your comments go?

Comment: Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name -replace '(?<!_.*)\.tif', '-main.tif' }

The above was the fix but I don't understand what ?<! is doing. I'm guessing it means the same as "Not something with an Underscore"? 

I hope you didn't delete your posts; I was only trying to be clear about what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works:

What I have done is create a function for each task, but we could put it all into one function, but I thought it would be easy to explain like this.

We use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to grab everything in the directory called `DS.TIF`, `DS_A.tif`, or `DS_B.tif`. Once this is done we get a list of files that forum to those rules. Now it is simple as renaming them, but keeping the `6-100-DS` the same.

```
$Dir="F:\Test\Images"
Function Main{
$Files=Get-ChildItem $Dir -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*DS.TIF"} 
$Files | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "DS","DS-main" }
}

Function alt01{
$Files=Get-ChildItem $Dir -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*DS_a.TIF"} 
$Files | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_a","-alt01" }
}

Function alt02{
$Files=Get-ChildItem $Dir -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*DS_b.TIF"} 
$Files | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_b","-alt02" }
}
Main
alt01
alt02
```

Comment: Question: When I'm running my own scripts, I running them on the command line...one line at a time. I've just not tried this but it would appear that these functions are being run as a file? Is that correct? Or, is this script being copied into the command line? 

The solution is close enough. The DS cannot be used as a selector; that's just part of the sku.

Comment: { $_.name -replace '(?<!_.*)\.tif', '-main.tif' } 
This actually does a really nice job selecting images that don't have an underscore; which, essentially, selects all the main images.

Comment: The functions are just like variables. Instead of calling a variable you are calling a section of the script. When the function is ran it stores it in the powershell profile until you close that powershell window. Then you can call it anytime you want. RegEx way would work. If DS.tif is not going to be used on all images. You could use the RegEx option. I think you have answered your own question.